# Microsoft DaRT - Standalone System Sweeper

Tags: deployment, dart

**Envrionment:**  MDT 2012 on a Server 2008 R2 install.  WDS installed and working, MDT installed and working. Microsoft DaRT installed on server, tools.cab has been copied to the respective deployment shares and enabled in on each one in MDT.

**Situation**: Created a deployment share for Microsoft DaRT only (so other techs can just boot directly to some recovery tools via WDS)  Works fine, boots directly to DaRT with no issues.

**Problem**: The Standalone System Sweeper fails to run.  Clicking on it displays this error message: "The tool failed to run. Try choosing another tool."  The only option is to click OK and it takes me back to the Diagnostic and Recovery Toolset menu.

I have done a bit of google searching to not much avail.  Checked out some of the tehnet blogs.  Most errors with the SSS seem to be related to updating, not just *running* it.

If anyone has any ideas or thoughts, please feel free to share.

**Edit**:  Everything in our network is based off x64.  Our Windows 7 (7601) is 64bit enterprise, our WinPE generates an x64 wim and iso to boot into DaRT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I feel silly.

Turns out the best method to boot to DaRT PE was to install Dart on a workstation, create a bootable iso, extract the iso, find the boot.wim in the extracted directory under sources/boot.wim, copy that to the WDS server, and add it as a boot image.  Lo and behold, now it works like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

I boot this over the network without issues - The only recommendation I can make is to redownload the tools and the reburn the disk in case it some how became corrupt.

Comment: I think I may have just found the solution.  Use the DaRT tool to create a bootable media (iso) then extract taht to find the DartPE wim.  Mount that into WDS, and hopefully that should do it.  Starting now.  

Is that how you set yours up?